# create radiobutton group for each array returned as a document

Tags: meteor, nested, each

topics is a collection which returns a few documents. Each document has a few fields. One of the fields is a string array. 
I am trying to represent the values of a string array as a radio button group for each document returned. I am not able to give each group a unique name. I tried console.log statements and found that the radiobutton groups come out good but then gets messed up as the helpers are called more times than the number of documents returned.

My html

```
<template name=topics>
  {{#each topics}}
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectone" id="{{uniqueid}}"/></td>
      <td><textarea rows=4 name="topicname" readonly>{{name}} </textarea></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="{{dateCreated}}" name="datecreated" readonly/></td>
      <td>
        {{#each choices}}

          {{>radiogroup}}

        {{/each}}

      </td>
      <td><a href="#" name="edittopic">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>

  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name='radiogroup'>
  <li><input type=radio name="{{radiogroupname}}" />{{this}}</li>
</template>
```

My js:

```
Template.topics.helpers({
  uniqueid: function() {
    Session.set('topicid',this._id);
    return this._id;
  },
  choices:function() {
    return this.choices;
  },
});

Template.radiogroup.helpers({
  radiogroupname: function() {
    return(Session.get('topicid'));
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good use of a `Session` variable in that you are reusing it over and over to represent a given `_id` inside a loop. It will be constantly changing. Since you just need the `_id` of the parent object, you can use relative path notation in spacebars to access it in your template as follows:

```
<template name='radiogroup'>
  <li><input type=radio name="{{../_id}}" />{{this}}</li>
</template>
```

Then you don't even need your helpers. You don't need your `choices` helper in any case since `choices` is already iterable.